# Why does altering text string format produce different date timezones?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-format, date-formatting

```js
const a = new Date("January 1, 2019").getTime(); // 1546329600000
const b = new Date("2019-01-01").getTime(); // 1546300800000
```

It seems that `a` produces a UNIX millisecond timestamp in my local time (PST) and `b` gives me a UTC timestamp. Tested in Google Chrome 76.

Why?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is JavaScript ran through Google Chrome client browser.

Comment: "*It seems that `a` produces a UNIX millisecond timestamp in my local time (PST) and `b` gives me a UTC timestamp.*" all Unix timestamps are in UTC. Seems that `new Date` actually gives you different results in regards to timezones

Comment: Parsing of the first string is implementation dependent, likely it's treated as local. The second string is parsed as UTC, per ECMA-262. Both time values are UTC.